# ASP.NET MVC ModelBinder Custom Field Mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, instagram

I have a api that I am working with that is going to do a POST of some JSON to one of my server side methods.

I am working on creating some C# classes that map to that JSON's structure. My problem is one of the fields that is posted to me is named "object" and its a string.

Here is an example of the JSON that is sent to me....

```
[
{
    "subscription_id": "1",
    "object": "user",
    "object_id": "1234",
    "changed_aspect": "media",
    "time": 1297286541
},
{
    "subscription_id": "2",
    "object": "tag",
    "object_id": "nofilter",
    "changed_aspect": "media",
    "time": 1297286541
},]
```

Here is my issue. How do I tell the model binder to take the json "object" property and map it some a different name in my C# class since object is a reserved word?

```
 public class InstagramUpdate
{
    public string subscription_id { get; set; }
    public string object_id { get; set; }
    public string object { get; set; } //<-- what should I do here??
    public string changed_aspect { get; set; }
    public int time { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this makes sense?

Thanks!

Comment: and your actionmethod expects an InstagramUpdate object and the objectis null??

Comment: Not even to that point yet. I don't know how to model in c# what the JSON looks like since one of the names is "object" and that is a reserved word in C#. The method sig would look like this tho.  [HttpPost]
        public string Process(InstagramUpdate[] data)
        {
        }

Comment: try directly :  [HttpPost] public string Process(InstagramUpdate postedObject) { };

Comment: i mean, in the posted actionmethod, you should add the parameter the object that you wish to get from the client, be it via JSON or POST.

Comment: I have to support multiple InstagramUpdate objects :( it will always come in as an array, even if there is only 1. I think the modelbinder will work just fine with that method signature, the problem is that I don't know what to call the field in my c# class as "public string object {get;set;}" doesn't compile since you can't have a variable named "object"

Comment: to kind of overrite keywords in c# you prefix them with "@". i.e. : @object will be treated as if the name of the variable is "object" etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just to have the answer here as well :

try to prefix your c# reserved keyword with "@" if you want to set it as a varible/attribute name.

i.e:

```
public class InstagramUpdate
{
    public string subscription_id { get; set; }
    public string object_id { get; set; }
    public string @object { get; set; } //object will be here the prop name
    public string changed_aspect { get; set; }
    public int time { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Welcome. sorry i misread the question in the first place.kind of tired:)